# Ability to select From address when workflow triggers email alert.

Tags: email

I have a workflow rule that is triggered upon Lead Creation, which sends out an email to their lead and introduces them to their responsible rep. The workflow triggers from a webform on the website. The Webservice User creates the lead and then it is reassigned to the corresponding agent.

The "From address" should be the responsible agent, or current Owner, of the record.

There is no option for this, and the current user is the webservice user.

Is there any way around this?

Regards,

James